# Nested Tabs in Ckeditor Dialogbox

Tags: javascript, tabs, dialog, nested, ckeditor

Ckeditor provides the feature to have Tabs in to the dialog box created using plugin. It uses the [dialog definition](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition) for creating the tabs.For Example :

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'testOnly', function( editor ) {
    return {
        title:          'Test Dialog',
        resizable:      CKEDITOR.DIALOG_RESIZE_BOTH,
        minWidth:       500,
        minHeight:      400,
        contents: [
            {
                id:         'tab1',
                label:      'First Tab',
                title:      'First Tab Title',
                accessKey:  'Q',
                elements: [
                    {
                        type:           'text',
                        label:          'Test Text 1',
                        id:             'testText1',
                        'default':      'hello world!'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
} );
```

This Generates the Tabs next to each other.So my question is :

> **How can i use this plugin to have Nested Tabs ? so that I could be
>   able to have 2-3 Sub/Nested tabs under the parent one.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. CKEditor API has never considered such an use–case.

But you might try some 3rd–party solution like jQuery UI or Bootstrap. For instance Drupal 8 uses CKEditor with a custom dialog system.

Comment: Thanks Buddy..!! Custom HTML is the only solution as Ckeditor is not providing Nested Tabs and I hope it will be added soon in its Library.